# Calling profile of a child module from profile defined in parent POM

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have the following profile in parent POM :

```xml
<profile>
    <id>myprofile</id>
    <activation>
       <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
    </modules>
</profile>
```

Now in my child POM of module2 I have the following profile :

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>module2profile</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>mywar</finalName>
            <plugins>
            ....
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

My requirement is that from the parent POM profile, instead of referring "module2", I want to refer to profile "module2profile". 
I need this because in my module2 I am creating 2 different war files (one that is created normally while the other is created by "module2profile").

Comment: There is no inheritance between maven profiles. You can not refer to a profile defined in a child POM. Why don't you create a module for each WAR instead of creating profiles? It would allow you to trigger the right module from the parent POM.

Comment: In addition: activation of profiles is pretty static, and it won't allow you to activate much of them depending on whatever you determine during your build.

Comment: @Magleff thanks for your reply. In my project I want to create two different types of war from the same source code but with different configuration files. In this scenario is it possible to create two different modules from same project (and obviously same POM)?

Comment: If you want to create two wars sharing the same source code (and possibly have different configuration files), try [WAR overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html). That's the best way. "Overlays are used to share common resources across multiple web applications." It is pretty much what you are looking for, isn't it ?